# Loop through nested json in logstash with ruby

Tags: json, ruby, logstash

My data is deeply nested JSON, and I need to index a sum of certain fields. As new to Ruby, I've tried the following (with some variations of *#i* ) but it only throws a _rubyexception:

```
ruby { code => '
 i = 0
 sum = 0
 while i < event.get( "[foo][bar][faz]" ).length do
  sum += event.get( "[foo][bar][faz][#i][[baz]]" )
  i += 1
 end
 event.set( "sum", sum )
'
}
```

How should I properly loop through the nested fields to get the sum?

e.g. This works:

```
ruby { code => '
  event.set( "sum", event.get( "[foo][bar][faz][0][[baz]]" ) + event.get( "[foo][bar][faz][1][[baz]]" ) )
 '
}
```

but the real amount of events vary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution to my question:

```
ruby { code => '
  i = 0
  sum = 0
  while i < event.get( "[foo][bar][faz]" ).length do
   sum += event.get( "[foo][bar][faz][" + i.to_s + "][[baz]]" )
   i += 1
  end
  event.set( "sum", sum ) 
 '
}
```